# Question in number of bits in C programming

Tags: c, integer, sizeof

If I do

int a = **3**, then 3 will be represented in binary with 32 bits.

If I do

char a = **3**, then 3 will be represented in binary with 8 bits.

My question is before doing the initialization with the value, how many bits does **3** get represented with?

(In other words, how many bits does the "3" has on the right-hand side of the equal sign)

Comment: You can't say for sure. You can only say that it is of type `signed int` which can vary depending on your system. I'd recommend you `#include <stdint.h>` to be able to define the size and signedness of constants, e.g. by using the macro `UINT32_C(3)` to represent 3 as an unsigned 32-bit int.

Comment: I heard of some implementations having `int`-s with 128 bits, and 16 bits `char`-s (emulated). Check by buying then reading the latest ISO C standard, or at least [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it using `sizeof` operator. It will give you size of argument in bytes. Just try to get size of `int`, `a` and `3`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(a)); // gives 4 bytes (32 bit) on my PC 
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(int)); // gives 4 bytes (32 bit) on my PC 
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(3)); // gives 4 bytes (32 bit) on my PC 

    return 0;
}
```

Also, `3` has type of `int`. So its size is equal to size of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

It's very *common* that `int` has 32 bit, but it's not guaranteed. It can be 16 or 64 too. Or higher.

A single `3` is an integer literal of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an object of the type `int` is implementation defined The standard makes only the requirement that `INT_MAX` shall not be less than `+32767` that is `2 ^ 15 - 1`

If in your system the size of an object of the type `int` is equal to 4 then an integer constant like `3` will occupy a block of memory equal to `4` bytes.

Pay attention to that for example character integer constant are also have the type `int`.

So in the both these declarations

```
char a = 3;
```

and

```
char a = '\3';
```

the constants `3` and `'\3'` having the type `int` occupy `4` bytes if `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The `3` is called an *integer constant* and it has a type much like any named variable. It is always type `int` if the number typed can fit inside an `int`. Otherwise, if it can't fit, the compiler will try to fit it inside a `long`, then `long long`.

There's various rather intricate rules for how this is done, I won't mention all the dirty details here - those who are interested in that can check the tables in the C standard 6.4.4.1. For the average programmer it is probably enough to know that we can also enforce the integer constant to be unsigned by adding a `U` suffix or force it to be `long` by adding a `L` suffix. That is `3U` or `3L` or a combination `3UL`. (Lower case `u` and `l` works too.)

On real-world computers, `int` is always 2 or 4 bytes large. `long` is either 4 or 8 bytes large. Example from a 64 bit Linux computer with 4 byte `int` and 8 byte `long`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
int main (void)
{
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));        // 4
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(3));          // 4
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(3L));         // 8
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(2147483647)); // 4, fits int
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(2147483648)); // 8, doesnt fit
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3675zv

Answer (score 0):

The question "how many bits does 3 get represented with?" is actually tricky. If we can find the 3 then we can answer it. So the question is: *where is the 3*?

What really happens is that:

```
int a = 3;
```

is the same as:

```
int a;
a = 3;
```

The compiler makes sure there will be 4 bytes of space for the variable `a` (it does this at compile time), and then it also puts an instruction in the program which stores the number 3 in that space when you run the program.

We can use this useful online tool to compile a program and see what assembly/machine code the compiler actually outputs: https://godbolt.org/z/a9Pohn

In this case, I entered the program:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    a = 3;
}
```

and compiled it with "x86-64 gcc 10.2", no optimizations. Here is the compiled code (both assembly and machine code):

```
main:
 55                     push rbp
 48 89 e5               mov rbp,rsp
 c7 45 fc 03 00 00 00   mov DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x3
 b8 00 00 00 00         mov eax,0x0
 5d                     pop rbp
 c3                     ret
```

If we can read assembly we can see that the instruction the compiler chose to insert into the program, to initialize the variable `a`, was `mov DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x3`. And in machine code it is written `c7 45 fc 03 00 00 00`. The instruction is where the number 3 comes from.

The instruction is 7 bytes long. `c7 45` tell the CPU what kind of instruction this is ("put a specific number at a specific position in the stack frame"). `fc` is the position in the stack frame. And `03 00 00 00` is the specific number which it puts there (in little-endian format). This is the number 3 in the source code. So in this case, it takes up 4 bytes.

---

Note that it's not always the same. If we compile for an ARM CPU instead of x86-64, then these are the relevant instructions

```
mov r3, #3
str r3, [fp, #-8]
```

Unfortunately godbolt won't show us machine code, but [we can look up the MOV # instruction in the ARM manual](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289878994.htm) which tells us that the instruction is 4 bytes long, and the number being moved only takes up 2 of those bytes! The other bits are automatically zeroes. If you use a number that doesn't fit in 2 bytes, obviously it uses a different instruction.

Usually we don't talk about the sizes of instructions since they vary a lot more than data sizes. `int a;` always reserves 4 bytes (if your system's `int` is 4 bytes) but the instruction which puts the specific bits into that space can have varying sizes.

---

Even on x86-64, numbers can take up different amounts of space. If I do `return 0;`, the compiler translates that to `xor eax, eax` (`31 c0`). There is no number `0` in that instruction at all! (`31 c0` is all type of instruction, no data)